# Excel: SUMPRODUCT with IF and ISERR showing #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What might be wrong with this formula, so that it gives me `#VALUE!`?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(R6:R80; (IF(ISERR(FIND("Db"; AU6:AU80)); 0;1)))
```

Example values:

```
    |  R  |  AU  
---------------
  6 |  3  |  Db 
  7 |  3  |  Dm 
  8 |  1  | DbMi 
  9 |  1  | DmMi 
 10 |  1  |  Mi 
... | ... | ...
```

Oddly enough: the formula builder shows the correct value.

[image: Proof for the above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(R6:R80; --(ISNUMBER(FIND("Db"; AU6:AU80))))
```

[image]

If you want to use the IF then you need to Array enter the formula in the first cell with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: I don't care for the IF, it was more like a didn'twork-around. Your solution works like a charm. Thanks!

BTW, why does it work?

Comment: The `--` turns the TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 respectively.

Comment: And it does if you array enter the formula.  But this way makes it so you do not need to array enter.